# How to set default value by many2one field in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have following **feeder_data** class in **'company_id1'** I will select name of company.That company name has to  set default value at **data_value** class 'company' field .It should have selected name as default value there

```
class feeder_data(osv.Model):
    _name = "feeder.data"
    _rec_name= "company_id1"

    _columns = {
        'company_id1': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Substation', required=True),
        'date_of1':fields.datetime('Date',),
        'combine2':fields.one2many('data.value','combine','Details'),
        }
class data_value(osv.Model):
    _name = "data.value"
    _rec_name = "mega_wat"
    _columns={
        'company':field.char('Comapny'),
        'Hours':fields.integer('Folio'),
        'mega_wat':fields.float('Mega Watts'),
        'combine':fields.many2one('feeder.data','details'),
    }

data_value()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For setting the default value of **company_id1** in model  `feeder.data`
try this way:

```
def _default_company(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    user = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context)
    if user.company_id:
        return user.company_id.id
    return self.pool.get('res.company').search(cr, uid, [('parent_id', '=', False)])[0]

_defaults = {

'company_id1': _default_company,
}
```